# Android: How to convert a CheckBox into a int

Tags: android

I want to convert an checkbox to int, example geo == 0; and mat == 0; to add with other operations if possible I appreciate it.

```
 package com.gustavo.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CheckBox geo;
    CheckBox mat;
    Button send;
    TextView say;
    EditText num;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bacon();

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String counter = num.getText().toString();
                  Integer.parseInt(counter, geo.getId());
                  Integer.parseInt(counter, mat.getId());

                  if(geo.isChecked()){
                      say.setText("Geografia: " + counter);
                  }
                  else if(mat.isChecked()){
                    say.setText("Matematica: " + counter);  
                  }

            }
        });
    }
    public void bacon() {
        geo = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        mat = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        say = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);   
    }

}
```

I wish you could help me because have a little time I begin with android 
and if possible post the code, it is my first post and wanted to see if it really is worth posting here.

Comment: You should rewrite "I want to convert a checkbox for int, this is my code I want to talk that geo its equals to 0 but is a checkbox, and when I try to do a Intenger has an error, and correct to String." - it's not clear what you're trying to do

Comment: Haha sorry, is because i am brazilian

Comment: @Dibai I am struggling to understand what purpose this is achieving. `geo.getId()` will just return the int of `R.id.checkBox1`, why are you trying to then pass it as the radix to `counter`?

Comment: @Dibai no worries, I'm just trying to grasp what you want the code to do so I can help out ;-)

Comment: In fact it was to take the part where I put geo.getId () sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but here is some code that should show you how to do various things....

```
// Get text value the user entered
String counter = num.getText().toString();

try {
   // Convert user entry into integer
   int counterAsInt = Integer.parseInt(counter);

   // Check if the checkboxes are set 
   if (geo.isChecked()) {
     say.setText("Geografia: " + counter);
   } else if(mat.isChecked()) {
     say.setText("Matematica: " + counter);  
   }

   // Update checkboxes based on the user entry
   if (counterAsInt == 0) {
     geo.setChecked(true);
   }

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   // Oops, something that was not a number was entered, like "asdfadfasdf"
   say.setText("Please enter a number!");
}
```

Comment: Glad to help. As someone else pointed out, you likely never need to pass a second argument to parseInt - that's for dealing with things like hexadecimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

**CheckBoxes** have two states only. Either `True` or `False`. You may also relate this to `1` or `0` respectively.

So, in your case, if you want to check if **geo** is **0** then the condition `if(geo.isChecked() == false)` or `if(!geo.isChecked())` would work fine.